# Knowing how many elements a set have?

Tags: set, pascal, freepascal, standard-library

I'm programming in Pascal and I'm trying to find if is there any already created function/procedure in the standard library or similar that allows me to know how many elements a set has?

I know how to do it by using a for loop and a counter increasing +1 when it finds an element (similar to what it has to be done when you want to print a set) but I was wondering if is there any other easier way of doing it, like I said, some predefined standard function/procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in Standard Pascal, no.  Many implementations have a nonstandard addition; for instance, GNU Pascal has the function `Card` (short for "cardinality"): http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/Card.html#Card .

**EDIT** I see this is tagged Free Pascal, and according to [this page](http://community.freepascal.org/bboards/message?message_id=757933&forum_id=24082), it lacks such an addition.  You have to loop over the set incrementing a counter.  At least you only have to loop over the elements actually in the set, rather than looping over all the possibilities and checking to see if each one is present...

Comment: Free pascal does not [seem to have it](http://community.freepascal.org:10000/bboards/message?message_id=233314&forum_id=24082) though.

Comment: Yes it doesn't but anyways, thank you the help, that function was exactly what I was looking for. I think I'll have to create the function or piece of code by myself.
I can't set the answer as accepted but I'll give you a +1 for taking your time to answer.

Also @SertacAkyuz thanks a lot for that link, very related with my question, marked as useful comment.

Comment: You asked "is there an easier way" and the answer is "no".  Why is that not acceptable?  It's not as though I personally designed Free Pascal to thwart you. :)

Comment: FPC has something like it, but only since weeks. See other answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your sets are 1,2,4 or 8 byte, one can use the recently introduced popcnt intrinsic.

This intrinsic is in system, but only in trunk (2.7.1)

```
function PopCnt(Const AValue: Byte): Byte;[internproc:fpc_in_popcnt_x];
function PopCnt(Const AValue: Word): Word;[internproc:fpc_in_popcnt_x];
function PopCnt(Const AValue : DWord): DWord;[internproc:fpc_in_popcnt_x];
function PopCnt(Const AValue : QWord): QWord;[internproc:fpc_in_popcnt_x];
```

The reason must probably be sought more in speeding up encryption/compression algorithms though, rather than classic sets.

Comment: Is good to know that now they have added that feature. Unfortunately I'm only allowed to use FPC 2.2.2 to compile my programs. Thank you for adding useful information to the answer.

Comment: How does this work? Does it use the SSE `popcnt` instruction on x86? `vcnt` on ARM? What happens if the program is run on an older processor without these instruction?

Comment: I think it depends on the chosen instruction set (-Cp etc) what it generates

Comment: So there is no fallback where it rewrites the code at runtime, when it was compiled for SSE4 and the processor does not have it? Catch SIGILL and override the SSE instruction with a supported one...

Comment: No, when you tell it to compile for say coreavx, the compiler IMHO rightly assumes that you mean to compile for coreavx (aka avx1) etc etc